# How to use multiple database payloads for DataWeave inputs

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I've currently got a working `Transform Message` (**[DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave)**) component in my Mule Project; which returns valid JSON.

What I need now is to update and add to that transformation with additional info from a second (and sometimes more) database payload(s).

I know that you can specify many inputs in the dw script (See [DW example tutorial](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-examples#multiple-inputs)).

```
%dw 1.0
%input in0 application/json
%input in1 application/json
%input in2 application/json
%output application/xml
```

[where in0, in1 and in2 are actual input names]

I'm not sure how to apply this method to multiple payloads derived from the database.

My aim is to have my base JSON be built by the first payload:

```
{
    "code": "some code",
    "title": "some title",
    "description": "some description",
    "keywords": []
}
```

which works fine.

But now I want the **keywords** array to be populated by the next payload, to become:

```
{
    "code": "some code",
    "title": "some title",
    "description": "some description",
    "keywords": [
        "keyword 1", "keyword 2", "keyword x"
    ]
}
```

**How to I map a JSON output in DataWeave from multiple inputs?**

---

**Details:**

- Mule EE Version: 3.7.2
- Anypoint Studio Version: 5.3.0

Comment: Do I create two transforms and populate them one after another? Do I call the database multiple times and assign their payloads to a `Payload` object?

Comment: You have to call databases and then assign their payloads to flowVars. Take a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the different payloads to flowVars, so, you can access from your dw script to these variables:

```
<set-variable variableName="myVar" value="{&quot;key1&quot;:&quot;value1&quot;}" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="myVar2" value="{&quot;key2&quot;:&quot;value2&quot;}" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    "a":flowVars.myVar,
    "b":flowVars.myVar2
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The documentation doesn't mention this, AFAIK.